# How do I clear data only but not formulas on google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am building a daily checklist that uses a trigger to make a new tab every night at 12pm. The code is below - but I need the code to clear the content of those cells, not the underlying formulas. I assume instead of "var rangetoclear" it must be something else, but I could not find on help page.

Can anybody help?

Here is the code:

```
/* DASHBOARD---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Edit this section to change the dates tabs are created for and the range of data that will be cleared each time! */
  
  var numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab = 0
  var rangeToClear = 'F8:I1003'
  
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   // get the spreadsheet object
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); // set the first sheet as active

  // Sets date for add tab & date for delete tab
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var today = new Date();
  var addWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() + (numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab * MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "MM-dd-yy"); 
  
  // Adds tab
  ss.duplicateActiveSheet(); //Copies current sheet
  ss.renameActiveSheet(addWeek); //Renames sheet to date from above
  ss.moveActiveSheet(1); //Moves sheet to the first position

  // Prepares tab (clears old content)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(addWeek);
  sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).clearContent()
}
```

Comment: I figured it out - I was using checkboxes as the root of the formulas - so when the box was checked, a time stamp and some other things got filled in. Originally, I was "clearContent()" for the outcomes rows, but I changed it to just clearing the checkboxes and it worked.

Comment: Check also my solution if it suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to get the formulas of the source sheet and for the range you want to clear `rangeToClear` and then copy the formulas to the duplicate sheet you just created after clearing its contents:

```
  const rangeToClear = 'F8:I1003';
  const source_sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const formulas = source_sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).getFormulas();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(addWeek);
  sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).clearContent()
  sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).setFormulas(formulas)
```

**References:**

- [getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas)
- [setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)

Answer (score 0):

```
sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).clear({contentsOnly: true});
```