# Google Spreadsheet Script, restore deleted rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Previous question with working code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66317759/google-sheets-script-get-and-set-data-from-different-spreadsheets)

The previous code that @iansedano has made works really well and does what I needed but right now I have to add two more tasks.

When someone types 2 the data stored in Spreadsheet2 in all rows except row 1 and the one with "2" should be copied back to Spreadsheet1. If there's no value in these rows the data copied to SS1 has all data except empty cells (example: SS2 has data in A-C-D-E-G-H, SS1 should have A(A)-B(C)-C(D)-D(E)-E(G)-F(H)).

I also have a formula on some cells on row 1, but every time I type 0 these formulas are deleted. I've tried to lock these cells but it does work. How could I avoid it?

By now I've tried to modify iansedano's script by adding `else if (undo){...}` but the script logs give me an error on `outputRange.setValues(output)` of the `else if (done) {...}` saying that rows number on data is 0, but in the range is 1.

Could this script work in shared Excel files too?

[image: Sample image]

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  let sheet = range.getSheet();
  let value = e.value;
  let row = range.getRow()

  let wantInfo = (
    sheet.getSheetName() == "Foglio1" &&
    row != 1 &&
    (
      range.getColumn() == 1 ||
      range.getColumn() == 2
    )
  )

  let done = (value === "0")
  let undo = (value === "1")

  if (wantInfo & !done) {
    let s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS1_ID")
    let s1sheet = s1.getSheetByName("Foglio1")
    let s1range = s1sheet.getDataRange()
    let s1values = s1range.getValues()

    let output = [];
    let rowToDelete;

    newS1values = s1values.filter((row, index) => {
      if (row[0] == value){
        rowToDelete = index + 1
        row.shift()
        output.push(row)
        return false

      } else return true 
    })

    let outputRange = sheet.getRange(row, 3, 1, 8);
    outputRange.setValues(output)
    s1sheet.deleteRow(rowToDelete)

  } else if (undo) {
    let s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS1_ID")
    let s1sheet = s1.getSheetByName("Foglio1")

    let s2range = sheet.getDataRange();
    let s2values = s2range.getValues();
    let headers = s2values.shift();
    
    s2values.pop();

    s2values.forEach(row => s1sheet.appendRow(row))
    sheet.clearContents()
    sheet.clearFormats()

    let headerRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,headers.length)
    headerRange.setValues([headers])
    
  } else if (done) {
    let s3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS3_ID")
    let s3sheet = s3.getSheetByName("Foglio1")
    
    let s2range = sheet.getDataRange();
    let s2values = s2range.getValues();
    let headers = s2values.shift();
    
    s2values.pop();

    s2values.forEach(row => s3sheet.appendRow(row))

    sheet.clearContents()
    sheet.clearFormats()

    let headerRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,headers.length)
    headerRange.setValues([headers])
  }
}

function init(){}
```

Comment: Could you provide a dummy spreadsheet or at least screenshots of the sample data and the desired output?

Comment: @NikkoJ. sample image added. Thank you for your patiente

Answer (score 0):

If you press 1 to your sheet2 and print `wantInfo` and `!done` before the first if statement, It will both print true.

**Example:**

[image]

This will satisfy the first if statement `if (wantInfo & !done) {` and causes this line of code `outputRange.setValues(output)` to raise an error since there is no data to set.

To fix the issue, update `if (wantInfo & !done)` to if `(wantInfo & !done & !undo)`

For formula getting deleted after using clearContents(), You can check Mario's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63418095/14606052) that uses [getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas) and [setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)

Also, Kindly check this link on [how to Troubleshoot your Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting).

Comment: Thank you,I solved both problems. Just how can I copy back the data without empty cells? I tried deleting the known empty cells like this: 'let rangeToDelete1 = sheet.getRange("B2"); rangeToDelete1.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS); let rangeToDelete2 = sheet.getRange("A3:A16"); rangeToDelete2.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);' but it's still not good because it removes some validation data, how could I get it done well? Could you say me if this code would work on a shared Excel file?

Comment: You can use Array.filter() to remove empty rows in your range. Example: `var test = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [], [9,10,11]]` to remove the empty sub-array you can use `var w = test.filter(e => e.length > 0)`. The output is `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [9, 10, 11]]`